# Taurus blazemeter yml multiple scripts in single scenario

Tags: jmeter, yaml, blazemeter, taurus

I want to know how to run multiple scripts in single scenario using Taurus Blazemeter inside of .yml configuration file.

Example:

```
scenarios:
  simple:
    script: someScript.jmx
    properties:
      hostname: localhost
      protocol: http
      port: 5017
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
scenarios:
  simple:
    script: [someScript.jmx, otherScript.jmx]
    properties:
      hostname: localhost
      protocol: http
      port: 5017
```

I have seen people creating custom tags like !include but i don't want to create any custom tag, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only have one [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) under "script" tag, however you can have multiple `scenarios` under one [execution](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/).

Something like:

```
execution:
- scenario: Scenario1
- scenario: Scenario2
  

scenarios:
  Scenario1:
    requests: 
      - url: https://example.com
  Scenario2:
    requests:
      - url: https://blazedemo.com
```

Also [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) are defined [differently](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables) in Taurus YAML:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      hostname: localhost
      protocol: http
      port: 5017
```